# Redux - check if action call was successful

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm looking for a good way to handle checking from component perspective what is the status of axios call inside a redux action. So in one of my components I have:

`import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';`

`const dispatch = useDispatch();`

and finally:

```
dispatch(deleteTest(id)).then(result => console.log(result));` // I would like to have .then logic as in this not working example - this would return status of axios call
```

While my action `deleteTest` looks like this:

```
export const deleteTest = id => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const { status } = await axios.delete(`/test/${id}`);
   // I would like to return status to action call
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple; Just return both status and error that are inside try/catch block. 
eg.

`export const deleteTest = id => async dispatch => {
      try {
         const { status } = await axios.delete(`/test/${id}`);
       // I would like to return status to action call
         return status;
      } catch(error) {
        return error;
      } 
    };`